# DQL query to find active users count

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dql

Can someone suggest me a DQL query to find  the count of active users in a repository in documentum.

Below is the query I am using but it is not giving correct results, can someone suggest?

```
select count(user_name) from dm_user u , dm_group g  where any g.i_all_users_names = u.user_name and  u.user_state=0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT count(user_name) FROM dm_user u, dm_group g  
WHERE ANY g.i_all_users_names = u.user_name 
AND u.user_state = 1
```

Property user_state values are:

- 0 user can log in (active)
- 1 user inactive
- 2 user locked
- 3 user locked and inactive

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT count(user_name) FROM dm_user WHERE user_state = 0 and r_is_group = false
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.